# adding a row id to multiple files with a continuous count in bash

Tags: bash

Say I have files A.tsv, B.tsv, and C.tsv.

Doing `cat -n A.tsv > A-id.tsv` is the output that I want for one file. How do you make a simple bash command to process all 3 files such that the row ID is continuous from the previous file and such that I can get 3 separate files, A-id.tsv, B-id.tsv, and C-id.tsv?

For example, if A.tsv has 3 lines, then B.tsv would start with 4 in an output format similar to `cat -n B.tsv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an awk alternative:

`awk '{outfile=FILENAME; sub(".tsv", "-id.tsv", outfile); printf("%6d  %s\n", NR, $0) >outfile;}' A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv`

Update, optimized version:

`awk 'FNR==1 {outfile=FILENAME; sub(".tsv", "-id.tsv", outfile);} {printf("%6d %s\n", NR, $0) >outfile;}' A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv`

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just `cat A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv | cat -n > ABC.tsv`?

via twalberg

> Or better yet, cat -n A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv > ABC.tsv

Update:

Considering this did not work for your linux distro, heres a number of alternatives:

`cat A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv | nl > ABC.tsv`

`cat A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv | grep -n '^' > ABC.tsv` -- this option results in a different type of format, namely: $linenumber: $line

Comment: Or better yet, `cat -n A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv > ABC.tsv`.

Comment: the row-id starts at 1 for each file, I need the row count to continue from file to file.

Comment: @PaulLam Maybe there are different versions of `cat` out there, then. The version I've got definitely does not restart counts between files...

Comment: piping it to `nl` did the trick! yes, it looks like my `cat` is different.

Comment: now how would I split the output into multiple files so they correspond with the input files?

Comment: @PaulLam This is a little more complicated. If I were you I would write a bash script to do this. I would take the three files and loop through each one keeping a counter and outputing line by line to a new file. I can't really think of any other way, especially not using simple bash commands.